# Firefox JavaScript concurrency

Tags: javascript, multithreading, firefox, concurrency

It seems that the latest Firefox browser (version 28.0) has built-in JavaScript concurrency. If you create two regularly executing functions via *window.setInterval()* method, and make one of the functions very CPU intensive, then the fast function will execute several times while the slow function is running.

This is not so in Google Chrome, Opera, and Internet Explorer. In these three browsers the functions run one after the other.

[Proof-of-concept JavaScript demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k2h7Z/34).

The fiddle boils down to this:

```
var timeout1 = window.setInterval(timeoutFunc1, 50),
timeout2 = window.setInterval(timeoutFunc2, 50);

function timeoutFunc1() {
    // It is given that window.output() is defined, and writes
    // it's parameter to the page for the user to see.
    window.output('1');

    // It is given that window.heavyComputation() is defined, and
    // performs CPU heavy computations.
    window.heavyComputation();
}

function timeoutFunc2() {
    window.output('2');
}
```

The output is something along the lines of:

```
1
2
2
2
1
2
2
2
...
```

Can anyone explain why this is so? Is JavaScript slowly being converted into a multi-threaded language by the browser implementations?

**UPDATE**

This turned out to be a fluke.

The JSFiddle that demonstrated the so called concurrency contains an error. When you enabled the second heavy function by setting `enableHeavyFunction` to `true`, then, because of the heavy function’s random nature, in some cases half way through execution an error is raised

```
Error: invalid arguments

this.spectrum   = new Float32Array(bufferSize/2);
```

`bufferSize` is to big, and Firefox JavaScript engine throws an error. Because of this, the fact that the heavy function ran is not registered in the output. So it appears that for three or four small functions only one heavy function is run. This is not so. Both functions run one after the other. It is just that the heavy function sometimes errors, and no output for it is written.

In Chrome this behavior did not happen because either it allows arbitrary first argument to `Float32Array` function, or it sets the first argument to some predefined maximum value.

See comments for the updated JSFiddle that uses a blocking function instead of the really large function. As can be seen, it clearly shows that JavaScript is single-threaded across all browsers.

Comment: Original idea expressed in my post http://valera-rozuvan.github.io/nintoku/new/age/javascript/concurrency/the-new-age-of-javascript-concurrency/ .

Comment: Why make your `heavyComputation` so long and complex? Do you experience this behavior with a simple function that blocks for a few seconds using `Date()` objects?

Comment: @cookiemonster I make my `heavyComputation` so long to make sure that I clearly see if one function runs several times while the other one is running. If both functions are fairly the same, then there is no way to tell how they are being run. In real world cases this matters. For example in a complex animation, it would be beneficial if I could run some other functions in parallel without resorting to some trickery (such as running necessary functions periodically from the complex animation function).

Comment: A function doesn't need to be long to make it block for a long time. Here's a much simpler demo. http://jsfiddle.net/6K2gf/ I can't test FF28 right now. Does the long-running code block for 5 seconds in the beginning?

Comment: @cookiemonster I have updated the JSFiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/k2h7Z/37/ . It is now using `heavyFunction2()`. This function is taken from your example - it is a strictly blocking function. The updated demo now runs the same in Google Chrome and Firefox. Why does the demo behave differently when the demo is using the `heavyFunction1()` function?

Comment: Yes, the reason I used such a blocking function was to see if there actually were parallel threads running. I can't take the time to examine all the code in either example, but in your first example, since there seems to be a 1:3 ratio of long to short running calls, I'm *guessing* that Firefox's `setInterval()` implementation is somehow able to queue up the short-running ones more aggressively, squeezing them in where possible. I really don't know for certain, but I'm guessing it's just an implementation issue.

Comment: ...Either way, I don't know what you ultimately need, but if you were planning on relying on the consistent synchronization of two `setInterval` timers both running at roughly the same duration, I wouldn't count on it.